# PHP regex to test for punctuation in string that does not have at least one space immediately before or after

Tags: php, regex

I need help detecting when a string contains punctuation that does not have a space before or after it, or end of line.

It is difficult for me to explain in words, so I will try by example:

This should pass test:

```
hello, my friend
hello ,my friend
hello , my friend
hello my friend
hello my friend.
```

This would fail test:

```
hello,my friend
hello, my friend,have a nice day
```

The function I am hoping is simple like this:

```
function punctest($str)
{
    if (preg_match("[:punct:]",$str))
    {
        if (SOME_REGEX_GOES_HERE)
        {
            $okay = 1; // punctuation found, but has a space before OR after it
        }
        else
        {
            $okay = 0; // punctuation found, not no space found either side
        }

    }
    else
    {
        $okay = 1; // no punct found
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on @Riaz's answer, you just want to reject string that matches `/\S[[:punct:]]\S/`:

```
<?php                                                                                                                                       

function punctest($str)
{
    return !preg_match('/\S[[:punct:]]\S/', $str);
}

var_dump(punctest('hello, my friend'));
var_dump(punctest('hello,my friend'));
```

prints

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex below finds punctuation with non-whitespace characters on either side. Modify to use whatever punctuation marks you're specifically interested in.

```
/\S[,;:.?!]\S/
```